# PHP - Database generates blank row when loading page

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a form which will submit information that inserts a row into a database (company details). The submission works ok but I also find that going to the page containing the form will insert a blank row in the database. Any idea why this may be? Code is as below:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='addnew.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='categoryAdd' value='Travel'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='EstablishmentNameAdd' value='EstablishmentName'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='Address1Add' value='Address1'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='Address2Add' value='Address2'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='Address3Add' value='Address3'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='Address4Add' value='Address4'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='PostcodeAdd' value='Postcode'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='NearestStationAdd' value='NearestStation'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='TelAdd' value='Tel'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='FaxAdd' value='Fax'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='EmailAdd' value='Email'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='WebsiteAdd' value='Website'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='text' name='DescriptionAdd' value='Description'/><br/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='test'/>";
echo "</form>"; 

$EstablishmentNameAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EstablishmentNameAdd']);
$CategoryAdd = $_POST['categoryAdd'];
$Address1Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address1Add']);
$Address2Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address2Add']);
$Address3Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address3Add']);
$Address4Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address4Add']);
$PostcodeAdd = $_POST['PostcodeAdd'];
$NearestStationAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['NearestStationAdd']);
$TelAdd = $_POST['TelAdd'];
$FaxAdd = $_POST['FaxAdd'];
$EmailAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EmailAdd']);
$WebsiteAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['WebsiteAdd']);
$DescriptionAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DescriptionAdd']);

$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT into establishment_id (EstablishmentName) values ('$EstablishmentNameAdd')");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from establishment_id where EstablishmentName = '$EstablishmentNameAdd'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
$ID = $row['EstablishmentID'];
$NAME = $row['EstablishmentName'];

};
$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT into establishmentdetails (EstablishmentID, EstablishmentName, category, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Postcode, NearestStation, Tel, Fax,
Email, Website, Description) values('$ID', '$EstablishmentNameAdd', '$CategoryAdd', '$Address1Add', '$Address2Add', '$Address3Add', '$Address4Add', '$PostcodeAdd', '$NearestStationAdd', '$TelAdd', '$FaxAdd', '$EmailAdd',
 '$WebsiteAdd', '$DescriptionAdd')");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this after all the echos:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
...
}
```

Wrap all the bottom code in that, so that way only if there is a post it will do the insert.

Comment: That's a poor way to do it. `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` is guaranteed to work. Yours would fail if a submission was legitimately empty.

Comment: @MarcB, yes true, but the OP doesnt want an insert on an empty post, thats where the issue is!

Comment: actually, he's doing an insert on GET, which is the whole problem. Simply saying "not empty POST" won't stop blank fields through. He'll stil have to add much more server-side validation.

Comment: @MarcB no his form is a `post`, but yes, there would have to be more validation, this is just a start

Comment: `...but I also find that going to the page containing the form will...`. The initial hit is a GET, then it's a post.

Comment: @MarcB, the OP means when he/she loads the page, the info (of nothing) gets put into the database

Comment: Yes. Exactly. He hits the page initially (GET, blank row entered into db), then submits the form (POST, non-blank row entered into db).

Comment: @Neal GET is the request method sent when you access a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are echoing out the form.. and then immediately inserting things into your database that don't exist yet.

You can try this:

```
if(count($_POST) > 0 && in_array('EstablishmentNameAdd',$_POST)) {
$EstablishmentNameAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EstablishmentNameAdd']);
$CategoryAdd = $_POST['categoryAdd'];
$Address1Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address1Add']);
$Address2Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address2Add']);
$Address3Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address3Add']);
$Address4Add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address4Add']);
$PostcodeAdd = $_POST['PostcodeAdd'];
$NearestStationAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['NearestStationAdd']);
$TelAdd = $_POST['TelAdd'];
$FaxAdd = $_POST['FaxAdd'];
$EmailAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EmailAdd']);
$WebsiteAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['WebsiteAdd']);
$DescriptionAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DescriptionAdd']);

$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT into establishment_id (EstablishmentName) values ('$EstablishmentNameAdd')");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from establishment_id where EstablishmentName = '$EstablishmentNameAdd'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
$ID = $row['EstablishmentID'];
$NAME = $row['EstablishmentName'];

};
$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT into establishmentdetails (EstablishmentID, EstablishmentName, category, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Postcode, NearestStation, Tel, Fax,
Email, Website, Description) values('$ID', '$EstablishmentNameAdd', '$CategoryAdd', '$Address1Add', '$Address2Add', '$Address3Add', '$Address4Add', '$PostcodeAdd', '$NearestStationAdd', '$TelAdd', '$FaxAdd', '$EmailAdd',
 '$WebsiteAdd', '$DescriptionAdd')");
}
```

Comment: :P sorry that was a typo.. I pulled the !. Thanks

Comment: why did you pick `EstablishmentNameAdd` as the caveat for the post?

Comment: Was just an example.. I picked that over the others because it seemed the most likely to be necessary. For example, you can have a business but not have a website. Or maybe you're in the middle of getting your establishment set up.. so you don't have a phone number just yet. However, all establishments will have a name. And at any time everyone associated with that Establishment will know that name.

Comment: I just explained why I picked it. If the OP has a problem with that field he can change it.

Comment: Really appreciate the help guys but for some reason it is still not working. One thing I neglected to mention was that the establishment_id table has an auto increment field for the unique id. Is that relevant at all? Interestingly when I refresh the page it doesn't generate a blank row.

Comment: I figured out the issue...below the code I've pasted to this query I had more php that I thought had been commented out. I was however using <!-- --> (i.e. the html comment code) so the PHP page was still processing it. Many apologies for wasting your time and thanks again.